# Cannot link shared library on qt creator (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries, qt-creator

Here is my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

DEPENDPATH += /home/khajak/CList/linker
INCLUDEPATH += /home/khajak/CList/linker

LIBS += -L/home/khajak/CList/linker -llibCListManager
LIBS += -L/home/khajak/CList/linker -llibCommandLineEngine
```

Here is the `/home/khajak/CList/linker` directory:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 khajak khajak     24 Mar 30 23:10 libCListManager.so -> libCListManager.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 khajak khajak     24 Mar 30 23:10 libCListManager.so.1 -> libCListManager.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 khajak khajak     24 Mar 30 23:10 libCListManager.so.1.0 -> libCListManager.so.1.0.0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 khajak khajak 344109 Mar 30 22:37 libCListManager.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 khajak khajak     29 Mar 30 23:10 libCommandLineEngine.so -> libCommandLineEngine.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 khajak khajak     29 Mar 30 23:10 libCommandLineEngine.so.1 -> libCommandLineEngine.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 khajak khajak     29 Mar 30 23:10 libCommandLineEngine.so.1.0 -> libCommandLineEngine.so.1.0.0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 khajak khajak 207537 Mar 30 18:24 libCommandLineEngine.so.1.0.0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 khajak khajak    285 Mar 30 23:15 linker.pro
```

Qtcreator throws an error:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -llibCListManager
:-1: error: cannot find -llibCommandLineEngine
```

Comment: `-llibCListManager` means you want to link with a library named `liblibCListManager.so`. Try `-lCListManager`.

Comment: @n.m. Right, that was the case, write an answer, so I can accept. P.S. Why would they make linking that way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting `man ld`

> ```
>   -l namespec
>   --library=namespec<br>
> ```
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by `namespec` to the list of files to link.  This option may be used any number of times. If `namespec` is of the form `:filename`, `ld` will search the library path for a file called `filename`, otherwise it will search the library path for a file called `libnamespec.a`.
>   On systems which support shared libraries, `ld` may also search for files other than `libnamespec.a.` Specifically, on ELF and SunOS systems, ld will search a directory for a library called `libnamespec.so` before searching for one called `libnamespec.a`. (By convention, a ".so" extension indicates a shared library.)  Note that this behavior does not apply to `:filename`, which always specifies a file called `filename`.

Thus, `-llibCListManager` means you want to link with a library named `liblibCListManager.so`. For `libCListManager.so` the correct option is `-lCListManager`.